# ZEND FW : Joining two tables from different databases

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, join, zend-db

I want to join two tables in differenet databases on the same server.
Could someone tell me how I could do this in Zend Frameworks Db adapter?

Answer (score 0):

see:

[connecting to two different databases with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516359/connecting-to-two-different-databases-with-zend-framework)

http://blog.keppens.biz/2009/04/zendapplication-multiple-databases.html

http://blog.ekini.net/2009/03/04/zend-framework-connecting-to-2-databases/

Comment: hi thanks for the reply...but i have alreday got connection to two dbs and can switch between two seemlessly...but dont know how to contrsuct the sql for a join of tow table sitting in two databases.

plz advice me..thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Build tableGateway from your dbAdapter before joining two tables from different database.

```
use use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

$someCondition=new Where();
$someCondition->equalTo('columnName',$columnValue);
//you can build $this->tableGateway from your DB adapter
$rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($someCondition) {
        $table2forInnerJoin = new \Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier('table2Name', 'table2Database');
        $select->join(array('table2Name'=>$table2forInnerJoin),"table1Name.id = table2Name.id");
        $select->where($someCondition);
});
return $rowset;
```

Answer (score -1):

If the databases are on the same server and your user have access to them both, you can use full path - SELECT database_name.table_name.col_name...

Otherwise there is no chance for you to join them because of the principle. The join is done by SQL server - which would need to login to the other database...

On Oracle there is a feature called DBLink... which offers abbility to link other table/view from different server. Not sure about MySQL.

To make queries using different adapters you can use:

```
$select1 = new Zend_Db_Select($adapter1);
$select2 = new Zend_Db_Select($adapter2);
```

But again, you are still limited in things like union of these two... You can't do that because of the very nature of how the database works

Comment: thx for the reply..but the thing is hw to do with zend....i hv adapters for each connection and by nature i hv to apply the query using one adapter..so hw do i use other db in a seperate adapter...
can u give me an example plz?

Comment: Edited the answer. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.