# How can use two database in same project in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a project in Zend Framework. I want call two database in same project, meaning I want to get values from the second database in the same project.

Please post step by step instruction with code and filename on how to connect to the two databases.

There is a related question here [connecting to two different databases with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516359/connecting-to-two-different-databases-with-zend-framework) but I could not understand the code. Can someone please post mor information about this topic.

Comment: The answer you have linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516359/connecting-to-two-different-databases-with-zend-framework is about as step by step as it comes and it is exactly what I have done with ZF DB before.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the other question is mostly self-descriptive 
* [connecting to two different databases with Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516359/connecting-to-two-different-databases-with-zend-framework)

In the first codeblock, two database connections are created with names 'db' and 'db2', and they are added to the Registry

In the second block, the connections are picked from the Registry

```
    public function init()
    {
         $this->db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
         $this->db2 = Zend_Registry::get('db2');
    }
```

You can then run your queries on the fetched objects.

To use this code

Copy the first code block and put it in "bootstrap.php"

Modify the necessary hostnames, database names and passwords

use the second code block in your app code/logic

Read more on Zend_Registry here
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html